# Converting GET into POST in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

Working with Datatables. Trying to get work function (which currently works ONLY with GET) with POST.

Based [on this discussion](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/691/pipeline-post/p1) I modified [this function](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) and got something like below. Now getting error message:

json.aaData is undefined @ line 99

[Whole code is here](http://pastebin.com/UcM8N17L)

```
        jQuery.post( sSource, aoData, function (data) { 
            /* Callback processing */
            oCache.lastJson = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);

            if ( oCache.iCacheLower != oCache.iDisplayStart )
            {
                data.aaData.splice( 0, oCache.iDisplayStart-oCache.iCacheLower );
            }
            data.aaData.splice( oCache.iDisplayLength, data.aaData.length );

            fnCallback(data)
        },"json" );
    }
    else
    {
        json = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oCache.lastJson);
        json.sEcho = sEcho; /* Update the echo for each response */
        json.aaData.splice( 0, iRequestStart-oCache.iCacheLower ); // <- this line
        json.aaData.splice( iRequestLength, json.aaData.length );
        fnCallback(json);
        return;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try providing more details, or localising the problem, so more people will try to answer.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili I really don't know, what's problem. I provided info, that I know

Comment: @LukaRamishvili But, I have suggestion that, It's something related with variable names.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's not my code. Please take a look at links that I provided

Comment: Guys, I found error: PHP returns value  with 1-2 second delay jQuery.post doesn't wait for response, I think. How do you think, is it possible to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the full code sample you provided, couldn't possibly be the full code, because it's only 75 lines long, and you are getting an error that says you have an undefined property on line 99.

However, you did say that this line:

```
json.aaData.splice( 0, iRequestStart-oCache.iCacheLower );
```

is giving you the undefined error.  What's happening is you are trying to access the splice function of a property aaData which does not exist on your json object for some reason.

So if you open up your JavaScript console and type json.aaData, you will see that it returns undefined.  So whatever is supposed to set the aaData property of the json variable is not doing so.  I hope this helps you track down your error.

Comment: Ok so based on your screen cast it looks like the JSON object you're getting from question.php is returning with a property called aaData.

I would suggest clicking on the tab "Script" to the right of Console.  And where it says "Inline" click that and look for the file that contains your script.

Next scroll down to the line number that the aaData property is being access and click the green line number.

You should see a little red dot appear next to the number.  That's setting a breakpoint.  Now look on the right for your json variable and see if aaData is set.

Comment: Is undefined. Please take a look at original version of script http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html  lines 80-91 I changed to Post. I think something goes wrong because of this

Comment: Guys, I found error: PHP returns value  with 1-2 second delay jQuery.post doesn't wait for response, I think. How do you think, is it possible to fix that problem?

Comment: Hey, so you could setup an interval function to keep asking for it until it either gets it or timesout:

var secondsCounted = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if ( json.aaData ) {
        //do what you need to do and clear interval
        //...do stuff
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        if (secondsCounted == 10) { 
            console.log('json.aaData not found due to timeout');
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        secondsCounted++;
    }
},1000);

Answer (score 1):

It's `jQuery.post( sSource, aoData, function (data) {`. You have `aoData`, but in the code you reference `aaData`. It may be a typo.

Comment: Now, json.aoData is undefined @ line 99

Comment: Guys, I found error: PHP returns value  with 1-2 second delay jQuery.post doesn't wait for response, I think. How do you think, is it possible to fix that problem?

Comment: `$.ajax({...type: "POST", response:function(data){/*do something with data*/}...});`

Comment: I resolved this problem already. Can you pls take a look at this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612904/jquery-alternative-to-php-foreach