# jQuery alternative to PHP foreach()

Tags: jquery, json

When I manually push params one-by-one like this: aoData.push( { "name": "process", "value": "fetch" } ); it works well, without any error message.

But, now I want to, declare array tableXtraPostParams at the top of script and push one by one this array's params into aoData

Here is piece of code works fine

```
var tableXtraPostParams = {
    "process":"fetch",
    "which":"mine"
};
$.each(tableXtraPostParams, function(n, v){
    aoData.push( {
       "name": n, 
       "value": v
    } );
});
```

But I'm getting error message in JS log

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

## UPDATE

I know that this error related with my modification. (Because when I remove `$.each`, I don't get any error like this)

Here is what Aodata looks before push

```
[Object { name="sEcho", value=1}, Object { name="iColumns", value=8}, Object { name="sColumns", value=""}, Object { name="iDisplayStart", value=0}, Object { name="iDisplayLength", value=25}, Object { name="mDataProp_0", value=0}, Object { name="mDataProp_1", value=1}, Object { name="mDataProp_2", value=2}, Object { name="mDataProp_3", value=3}, Object { name="mDataProp_4", value=4}, Object { name="mDataProp_5", value=5}, Object { name="mDataProp_6", value=6}, Object { name="mDataProp_7", value=7}, Object { name="sSearch", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex", value=false}, Object { name="sSearch_0", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_0", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_0", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_1", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_1", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_1", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_2", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_2", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_2", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_3", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_3", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_3", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_4", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_4", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_4", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_5", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_5", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_5", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_6", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_6", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_6", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_7", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_7", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_7", value=true}, Object { name="iSortingCols", value=1}, Object { name="iSortCol_0", value=0}, Object { name="sSortDir_0", value="asc"}, Object { name="bSortable_0", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_1", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_2", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_3", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_4", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_5", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_6", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_7", value=true}]
```

Here is after push

```
[Object { name="sEcho", value=1}, Object { name="iColumns", value=8}, Object { name="sColumns", value=""}, Object { name="iDisplayStart", value=0}, Object { name="iDisplayLength", value=25}, Object { name="mDataProp_0", value=0}, Object { name="mDataProp_1", value=1}, Object { name="mDataProp_2", value=2}, Object { name="mDataProp_3", value=3}, Object { name="mDataProp_4", value=4}, Object { name="mDataProp_5", value=5}, Object { name="mDataProp_6", value=6}, Object { name="mDataProp_7", value=7}, Object { name="sSearch", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex", value=false}, Object { name="sSearch_0", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_0", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_0", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_1", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_1", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_1", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_2", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_2", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_2", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_3", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_3", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_3", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_4", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_4", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_4", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_5", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_5", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_5", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_6", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_6", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_6", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_7", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_7", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_7", value=true}, Object { name="iSortingCols", value=1}, Object { name="iSortCol_0", value=0}, Object { name="sSortDir_0", value="asc"}, Object { name="bSortable_0", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_1", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_2", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_3", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_4", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_5", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_6", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_7", value=true}, Object { name="process", value="fetch"}, Object { name="which", value="all"}]
```

Comment: You declared aoData as an array ?

Comment: @ubercooluk aaData is Json like `{ "aaData": [
["AAA","BBB","100","2"],
["AAA","BBB","100","2"],
["AAA","BBB","100","2"]
] }`

Comment: What ubercooluk is saying is that bare-object's do not have a push method.

Comment: `aoData[ 'name' ] = n; aoData[ 'value' ] = v;` although it seems like  you expect `aoData` to be an array and it isn't. Is it still unparsed JSON (i.e. a string)?

Comment: @Juhana `aoData.push( {
       "name": "process", 
       "value": "fetch"
    } );` works well. So what I want to do is to automate this process

Comment: I don't understand the question. Automate how? Which line causes the error message?

Comment: Note that the code you posted works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gRJDN/

Comment: @Juhana look when I manually push params one-by-one like this: aoData.push( { "name": "process", "value": "fetch" } ); it works well. But, now I want to, declare array `tableXtraPostParams` at the top of script and push one by one this array's params into `aoData`

Comment: As said, the code in the post works just fine. The error is somewhere else. Again, which line causes the error message?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11299/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-juhana)

Comment: @Juhana http://imgur.com/i0Iwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included datatables.js file?  For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can easily believe you're right.  I was going by the comments people were asking about aoData being an array.

Comment: Yes this file included. Even with this error message, my script works well. But I want to understand, what causes to occur this error message. Updated question with deeper details.Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The error is unrelated to your code unless you actually put your own code into jquery.js.

The file with that name however is broken. Did you modify anything in that file? If not, simply restore it with a fresh copy from http://jquery.com/

Comment: Redownloaded and placed fresh copy.No success. Updated question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

use `tableExtraParams.foreach`. And $.each's second parameter, `function (k, v)` doesn't work that way. It takes two parameters, *index* and *key*. k will be equal to 0,1,2,3 etc and v will be equal to "process", "which", etc. if you want to get key/value pair, use

```
var tableXtraPostParams = {
    "process":"fetch",
     "which":"mine"
};
$.each(tableXtraPostParams, function(n, v){
    aoData.push({
        "name": v, 
        "value": tableXtraPostParams[v]
    });
});
```